# How do I hide the status bar but not the ActionBar?

Tags: android

I want to show the action bar but hide the status bar except if the user swipes down in my Android app. How would I go about doing this?

The setSystemUIVisibility calls have been hiding everything for me.

Comment: This could help you: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html Search before post! =]

Answer (score 1):

try this: it's for [version 4.1](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html#41) and higher

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide the status bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

to [overlay](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html#EnableOverlay) the action bar

```
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: This only seems to work on 4.1? In 4.4. the status dissappears and then reappears, but it's working for me on 4.1.2.

Comment: @RyanCheu in the docs for 4.4 it says "you should never hide the status bar without hiding the action bar too" in other words it's programmed to show the two together. you can overlay the action bar there is more on that in the link (press version 4.1) in the answer